# How to add spaces in list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

Right now, I am creating a stick game for my school assignment and I print out stick visual for a user to see using "|". I go it to print out like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRiIf.png). but the vertical line after 9 is not spaced outright, causing the lines to be not above the assigned number. Code I'm using to print it out is

for i in zip(*Board):
    print(*i," ")

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Posting more of your code would be helpful.

One solution would be to print your numbers at the bottom in a fixed width.

```
a = 5
print(f'{a:05}') # zero padded on left, fixed length of 5
print(f'{a:5}') # space padded on left, fixed length of 5
```

This would allow you to alter your print statement's padding.

Another solution that is a bit more hackish would be to utilize the length of the string representation of the number.

```
len(str(i))
```